# Why ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've found it difficult to understand this problem:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
opc = int(self.qtjog_entry.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I'm confused because in another program without `self.`, this is possible. Look at this:

```py
qjogos = (int(qtjog_entry.get()))  # here, python casts str to int normally.
```

Can someone help me? Sorry, for my English, and I'm learning programming languages now. Thanks.

Comment: my best guess is, if you can add this to a function that runs wen u press a button, it should no more return an empty string i guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this simple example helps you udnerstand on your errors more.

**If I say `qjogos = (int(qtjog_entry.get()))` at the main block, like:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    pass

qtjog_entry = Entry(root)
qtjog_entry.pack()

qjogos = (int(qtjog_entry.get()))

b = Button(root,text='Click me',command=click)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I get youre same error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/PyProjects/Patient Data Entry/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    qjogos = (int(qtjog_entry.get()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**But now if i say it inside of a function, like:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click():
    qjogos = (int(qtjog_entry.get()))
    print(qjogos)

qtjog_entry = Entry(root)
qtjog_entry.pack()

b = Button(root,text='Click me',command=click)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I dont get any error and the number is printed in the terminal.

What happens in the first code is that, initially when the program runs, the value of whats inside the entry box is `''` (empty sting) which is not an int and hence cannot be converted to an integer using `int()`. So you have to enter the value then click on a button which calls the function and then gets the value which is inside the entrybox at the time you clicked the button.

I hope this is what you meant in your Q and that it clears your doubt, let me know if any more doubts. Explained it more cause you mentioned you're new to programming, cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.qtjog_entry.get()` returns an empty string; you can't use `int()` on an empty string. Without having more context, it's hard to tell exactly what's wrong here.